# Executing add-in from Python script?

Tags: arcpy, python-addin

I would like to execute the [Curves And Lines](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=b59665cb906a435da3f8c45332d7cfdf) add in from my Python script.

Is there any interface for working with add-in inside of a Python script?

Comment: It sounds like you want to use tools from the add-in inside your own script, rather than the entire add-in, is that correct?  If you run each tool manually you should be able to get a Python Snippet from the geoprocessing history and use those as a basis for calling each tool from within your script.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want to do. I will try that when I'm back in the office.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not say where you wish to run your Python script but, in any event, since Python AddIns only work from within ArcMap I think the approach you should take is to absorb the code from that addin into your own addin.

From the help for [the pythonaddins module](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/python-addins/the-pythonaddins-module.htm):

> The `pythonaddins` module can only be used within a Python add-in. It
>   cannot be used in stand-alone scripts or geoprocessing script tools.